# How to create a stored procedure from another stored procedure dynamically in OracleI have

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

I have a Stored Procedure that outputs the DDL of another Stored Procedure. I need to execute this DDL dynamically. Meaning, the second Stored Procedure should get created when the first Stored Procedure is executed.

Here's the pseudocode for P_GEN:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_GEN
AS
c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;  
stmt varchar2(4000);
   
BEGIN

open c1 for  
SELECT TXT FROM 
(
SELECT 
        'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_DEL' ....
    TXT
    FROM TBL
) ;

DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c1);

END;
/
```

P_DEL, when created, would have the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_DEL
AS
BEGIN
    DEL('TEMP1');
    DEL('TEMP2');
    DEL('TEMP3');
END;
/
```

I need P_DEL to be created when P_GEN is executed. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps, instead of returning the `CREATE PROCEDURE` text, you should just execute it using `DBMS_SQL`.

Comment: I am not getting the syntax right for it. I tried adding these: 

    iCursorID := DBMS_SQL.Open_Cursor;
    DBMS_SQL.Parse (iCursorID,'c1',DBMS_SQL.native);
    iReturned := DBMS_SQL.Execute (iCursorID);
    DBMS_SQL.Close_Cursor (iCursorID);

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the problem.

Sample tables (that should be - I guess - deleted):

```
SQL> select count(*) from temp1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

SQL> select count(*) from temp2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14
```

This is table that contains PL/SQL code, i.e. a `create procedure p_del` statement:

```
SQL> select * from tbl;

TXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace procedure p_del as
begin
  del('temp1');
  del('temp2');
end;
```

Does `P_DEL` exist? Not yet:

```
SQL> select count(*) from user_objects where object_name = 'P_DEL';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

This is the `del` procedure which is being called from `p_del`; it (`del`) must exist, otherwise `p_del` *will* be created, but with errors. Disregard possible SQL injection at the moment, that's not the issue right now.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure del (par_table_name in varchar2) is
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    l_str := 'delete from ' || par_table_name;
  5    execute immediate l_str;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.
```

`p_gen` procedure; it reads contents of the `tbl` table and executes it. The outcome (in this example) is that `p_del` procedure gets created:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_gen as
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (select txt from tbl) loop
  4      execute immediate cur_r.txt;
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_gen;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Does `p_del` exist now? Yes:

```
SQL> select count(*) from user_objects where object_name = 'P_DEL';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

Let's run it:

```
SQL> begin
  2    p_del;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result: both sample tables are now empty:

```
SQL> select count(*) from temp1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> select count(*) from temp2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

---

I didn't quite understand whether `p_del` should also "automatically" be executed; it can be, just call it within `p_gen`'s loop, e.g.

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_gen as
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (select txt from tbl) loop
  4      execute immediate cur_r.txt;
  5      p_del;                             --> here
  6    end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_gen;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from temp1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue is PL/SQL code in table TBL is dynamically generated one line at a time, joining a few tables. 

So first row will be 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...' , 
second row would be 'AS', 
third row would be 'BEGIN', 
4th row would be "DEL('TEMP1');" 
... etc etc. 

All rows would need be UNION-ed in order to get the complete code for the Procedure. And that can vary dynamically. Not every time will the same number of tables will get deleted. 

Once the cursor is created dynamically with the PL/SQL code, how to get it executed is the question.